# cannot close the screen in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, screen

I am using `finish()` to close current activity before quit application in Android.

However, I cannot close screen in blackberry.

```java
public class Main_AllLatestNews extends MainScreen {

public Main_AllLatestNews() {
    super(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
}

private boolean Dialog() {
    final Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");
    d = new Dialog("确定离开？", new String[] { "是", "否" }, new int[] {
            Dialog.OK, Dialog.CANCEL }, Dialog.OK,
            logo) {
        public void setChangeListener(FieldChangeListener listener) {
            if (d.getSelectedValue() == Dialog.OK) {

            } else {
                d.close();
            }
        };
    };
    d.show();
    return (d.doModal() == Dialog.OK);
}

public boolean onClose(){
    if(Dialog()){
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }else
        return false;
}
}
```

Here is my `Main` class

```java
public class Main extends UiApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main theApp = new Main();
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public Main() {
    pushScreen(new MyScreen());
}

public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    private Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("logo_page.png");
    private BitmapField bmfield;

    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle("Oriental Daily");

        bmfield = new BitmapField(logo, Field.FIELD_HCENTER
                | BitmapField.FOCUSABLE) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                Main.this.pushScreen(new Main_AllLatestNews());
                Main.this.popScreen(MyScreen.this);
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly how you want your close behaviour to work.  Also, I can only read English, so I'm not 100% sure what your `Dialog` says.  I'm assuming it's something to do with closing the app (yes or no)?

Anyway, usually, my apps close by overriding the `onClose()` method in the `MainScreen` subclass.  You don't actually need to listen for the escape key.  `onClose()` will get called normally when the user escapes all the way out of the app, or presses the little button with the blackberry icon, and then selects **Close**.

```java
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

   /** @return true if the user chooses to close the app */
   private boolean showDialog() {       
      Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon.png");
      Dialog d = new Dialog("确定离开？", 
            new String[] { "是", "否" }, 
            new int[] { Dialog.OK, Dialog.CANCEL }, 
            Dialog.OK,
            logo);       
      return (d.doModal() == Dialog.OK);
   }       


   /** Shutdown the app? */
   public boolean onClose() {
      if (showDialog()) {       
         System.exit(0);
         return true;
      } else {
         // the user does not want to exit yet
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: got error, but i don't know how to see where is the error, bb don't have something like `logcat`

Comment: @Alan, got **what** error?  a compile error?  an error running the app?  how are you running the app?  from Eclipse in a simulator?  on a real device?  BlackBerry has logging, too, but we need some more information to help you.

Comment: @Alan, also, looking at your code, you can remove some code from `Main_AllLatestNews`.  You don't need to listen to `keyDown()` events, and the `Dialog` is now created by `showDialog()` in the root `MyScreen` class.  Looking at your code above, you are calling `pushScreen()` and then `popScreen()`.  You actually don't need to do that.  Just call `pushScreen()`.  The `Main_AllLatestNews` screen gets put on top of `MyScreen`.  You don't need to remove `MyScreen` from underneath.

Comment: `return (d.doModal() == Dialog.OK);` give me runtimeexception but `return (d.getSelectedValue() == Dialog.OK);` give me no error but will not close apps

Comment: [Dialog.doModal() should not throw exceptions](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html#doModal()).  `getSelectedValue()` is not the correct call.  You need to show the dialog and get the result, which is what `doModal()` does.  Please post an update to your code that shows how you are using the code I posted.  You can add it to the bottom of your code, under a section labeled **Edit:** if you would like to keep the original code, too.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alan, please use the code I posted.  I can't help if you don't use the code I showed you.  The code I posted goes in `MyScreen`, not in `Main_AllLatestNews`.  Don't use your `Dialog()` method.  Use `showDialog()` that I provided.  You are also still incorrectly calling `popScreen()`.  Please read all my comments.

Comment: @Alan, looking at your original code, I now realize that maybe you don't want the user to ever go back to the first screen?  Maybe it's a "splash screen".  If so, then you can put `showDialog()` and `onClose()` in the `Main_AllLatestNews` class.  But, you still don't really **need** `popScreen()`, and you should still use my full implementation of `showDialog()`.

Comment: can help me on another problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256464/list-view-show-out-of-order